# What is the difference in mysql BETWEEN OPERATOR and microsoft sql (MDB) BETWEEN OPERATOR

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, between

I have a table in mysql and sql with field name called zipcode (datatype TEXT), and both tables total records are same, if I run the between query

```
select zipcode 
from tablename 
where zipcode between '7895154245' to '9545781543'
```

in mysql and sql the result which I am getting is missmatched. Please let me know the how to match the both results.

Comment: Between char vd between number is different. The point is you want to compare numbers and MySQL does string comparison. Use:  `select zipcode from tablename where CAST(zipcode AS INT) between 7895154245 to 9545781543`

Comment: SQL is a language which is executed on a MySQL database. What do you mean by `sql BETWEEN operator`?

Comment: you can run between query on Text Type column like this. Your column type must be decimal or numeric. This query will return you unexpected result

Comment: Make sure the types of both columns are identical like @lad2025 said. Also, some implementation of between are inclusive, others are exclusive for the upper bound. MySql is inclusive.

Comment: When you say "sql", do you mean Microsoft SQL-Server?

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and the difference in the results?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I think `BETWEEN` is a standard SQL operator, and the standard says it's inclusive. What implementations violate this?

Comment: How are they mismatched? Different numbers of rows? Different orders? Try adding `ORDER BY zipcode` to see if that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql Between Operator - Between 1 & 10 means return from 1 & 10.
MDB (Sql) Between Operator - Between 1 & 10 means return from 2 & 10. It ignores 1 in the result. I have tested this query, please check it and confirm here. Thanks.